# Arduino sampling accelerometer

Tags: arduino, adc, timer

I have an analog accelerometer I want to sample at 100HZ, I also want to plot the data with time of each sample so I have acceleration over time. To keep track of time I was going to use millis(). To sample at 100HZ I can use a timer, but AnalogRead() has overhead and I was wondering how to sample at 100HZ correcting for the overhead of AnalogRead()???

Also sending data over serial has overhead, not sure how to compensate for this, I want to get acceleration over time plot that is at least somewhat accurate if possible. I dont have the money right now for a RTC chip

Comment: Note that the delay is _deterministic_ : the timer happens every 10 miliseconds, and your data appears on the serial port some time after that, but the time elapsed is the same every time. Note that it also needs to take less than 10ms to send each reading over serial, which may be the major limiting factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send transmit roughly 11 bytes per millisecond at 115200 baud. So as long as you restrict your output to 10 characters and a newline per sample, that should be fine.

The math behind that is 115200 baud means 115200 bit-times/second, and there are 10 bit-times per byte transmitted on the UART (start bit, 8 data bits, and stop bit). So 115200 / 10 = 11520 bytes / second = 11.520 bytes / millisecond (and I round down).

In summary, 100Hz sampling should be easy.

The canonical approach to interval timing is demonstrated in the BlinkWithoutDelay Arduino example. Consolidated it looks like the following:

```
long previousMillis = 0;
long interval = 10; // interval in milliseconds (10ms => 100Hz)

void setup() {
   // whatever
   Serial.begin(115200);
   Serial.println("Hello World");
}

void loop(){
   unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
   if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;

      // do your task
      Serial.println(analogRead(0));
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks great thank you!!!, Would I have another variable in setup() like startTime = millis() for the time to plot on the graph? I want to plot acceleration over time, but would I use startTime or add up all the millis() intervals in the loop as the total time for the acceleration to plot

Comment: Each time AnalogRead() is called at 100HZ my total time would be 1/100HZ = 10mS so I would be doing time = time + 10mS, and plot time variable with the data? or would I synch it with the time = time + (currentMillis - Previousmillis)

Comment: @zacharoni16 correct, you would simply imply the time in your external analysis as being 10ms intervals from some starting time t0. No need to output or store a time variable.

Answer (score 1):

from Arduino:
millis() - Returns the number of milliseconds since the Arduino board began running the current program. This number will overflow (go back to zero), after approximately 50 days.

it is a converted representation of the program counter, which keeps on running, regardless. Not to be confused with the delay() and delayMicroseconds(), which are basically per-calculated nop's. Using them between samples would have delays and growing skewing.

So using

```
if ((millis() - lastTime) > _Delay) {
  lastTime = millis();
  blah... 
}
```

would not skew. Likewise there is http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer library that will do the same thing. but in a more typical library and service format, that I use.

Where both of these will have some jitter, not skew, from other interrupts and other things going on. That said using the Timer1 interrupt to generate the 100Hz should reduce the jitter as best as possible. As exampled http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_TimerOne.html

Comment: The millis() function would not be a converted representation of the program counter. It is instead a counter that keeps counting at a 1msec rate as long as the program keeps running. The program counter in most programs like this is jumping all over and then eventually looping back to repeat its jumping all over pattern. The program counter of the MCU is not constant long length linear count - Unless someone made a nearly useless program made up of a memory full of NOPs and even then the linear run would only last a few milliseconds before the NOP sequence ended and crashed.

Comment: Thank you! Which time would I be plotting would I take the running millis() counter as the time to plot or should I add up all the times of the samples and thats the accurate time to send to plot on the graph with acceleration values?

Comment: I could be convinced that what was meant in this response was "cycle counter" rather than "program counter" if AVRs had such a thing :-) but @MichaelKaras comment is pedagogically accurate

Comment: The millis() is cumulative, so need to add them up. Only need to watch for a roll over.

Answer (score 1):

The analog read time is on the order of 10's of microseconds with most clock selection settings - nothing to worry about.  The serial is similar as vicatu said - 11 bytes in a milisecond.  You have ten milliseconds to do all your work in and the delays shouldn't really add up to more than a millisecond - should be no problem.  Just implement the time check as he showed in his post and you should be okay.